# How to check Cognito users admin-set-user-mfa-preference values

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have AWS cognito pool and created multiple users. For authentication purpose we enabled MFA, some users are using SMS and some users are using TOTP. So how to check which user is using SMS/TOTP from AWS cli like --sms-mfa-settings and --software-token-mfa-settings values....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple way here. Currently this information is not provided with the `ListUsers` action and so the only thing you can do is to ask for details of one specific user. If MFA is enabled **and** user set his/her preferences, you will see the following field in `AdminGetUser` action: `PreferredMfaSetting` with values `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` or `SMS_MFA`.

So:

```sh
aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id <value> --username <value>
```

The output may look something like this:

```json
{
    "Username": "your-email@example.com",
    "UserAttributes": [
        {
            "Name": "sub",
            "Value": "121b7a6d-2303-4d68-997a-28fa061f66d9"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        },
        {
            "Name": "phone_number_verified",
            "Value": "true"
        },
        {
            "Name": "phone_number",
            "Value": "+1234567890"
        },
        {
            "Name": "email",
            "Value": "your-email@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "UserCreateDate": "2020-11-07T12:00:43.722000+00:00",
    "UserLastModifiedDate": "2020-11-07T12:14:26.918000+00:00",
    "Enabled": true,
    "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
    "PreferredMfaSetting": "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA",
    "UserMFASettingList": [
        "SMS_MFA",
        "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA"
    ]
}
```